# decompose a string into array of int

Tags: java, arrays

What is the shortest and most efficient way to decompose a string array into an array of int's if the string looks like:

```
4 1 4 2 3
5 1 4 2 -1 6
```

The way I have it now is to use String split method and iterate the String array into int's.. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Efficient by what criteria - conciseness, speed, memory usage, or ...?

Comment: *Shortest* and *most efficient* are sometimes mutually exclusive. For example, bubble sort is shorter compared to quick sort, but quick sort is faster. Aso *most efficient* is an ambigious term. Do you want it to be memory-efficient or CPU-efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine - I'd just call `split(" ")` and then use `Integer.parseInt()` on the resulting elements.

If you could potentially have more than one space between the ints, you'll need something like `split("\\s+")` for it to work properly.

If that's what you're doing, I don't think there's a better way!

EDIT: Perhaps I should qualify the term *better* - I mean that for all practical purposes, unless you're really hitting performance critical issues, I'd stick with this method since it's clean and easy to understand what's going on!

Comment: Good answer, just a note, `split(" ")` will not cope with strings having more than one space between the elements (use `" +"` or `"\\s+"`) to be sure.

Comment: @dacwe thanks for that, I've edited accordingly - I just assumed there wouldn't be given the example but you're right, it's better to be sure!

Comment: @berry120 there may not be a better way practically but I have made some code to prove that academically there are far better ways.

Comment: @Farmor Yes - I've updated the answer to qualify what I meant now. Interesting answer though!

Answer (score 2):

Using `split()` consumes more space [and time], as new `String` objects are created, but it is far more elegant [and simple] then any other way.

unless performance is very critical, I'd stick with this way.

Comment: @dacwe: before the `split()` was used, there was 1 `String` object, and after it n objects. objects must be created. though the `char[]` is not being duplicated [instead the offset and size are being used] does not say objects are not created.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm **3times** faster than the split method! :)

Just for the fun of it I have made an algorithm  that is far faster than the split method.
Maybe nothing you should use as I would say split is cleaner and cleaner is far more important than speed. Also the Donald Knuth quote of premature optimizations are the root cause of all evil.

Output

```
1189ms // My algorithm first loop
3305ms // Split algorithm runtime first loop
1173ms // My algorithm second loop
3305ms // Split algorithm second loop
```

The code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class FarmorsOptimized {

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private static ArrayList getFarmors(String s) {
    ArrayList intArr = new ArrayList();
    int stopvalue = s.length() ;
    for (int i = 0; i < stopvalue;) {
        int negativ = 0;
        if (s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            negativ = 1;
        }
        intArr.add(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+1+negativ)));
        i+=2+negativ;
    }
    return intArr;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private static ArrayList getSplits(String s) {
    ArrayList intArr = new ArrayList();
    for(String str : s.split(" ")){
        intArr.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }
    return intArr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1 2 4 -6 7 1 2 4 -6 7 1 2 4 -6 7 1 2 4 -6 7 1 2 4 -6 7 1 2 4 -6 7 1 2 4 -6 7";
    int times = 1000000;
    //Just to init everything
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getFarmors(s);
        getSplits(s);
    }
    long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getFarmors(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getSplits(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getFarmors(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getSplits(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I'd advise using it in practice but academically it's an interesting approach!

Comment: yea, this is an overkill, for a simpler things that I am doing, but thanks for adding some new knowledge

Comment: please don't make announcements about '3 times faster' based on a microbenchmark. However, I'd love to see a real benchmark [random number, change the order of methods, etc...]. also note, that this solution also creates new objects `String` objects, and thus consumes more space. also, this solution seems to work only for ints in range [-9,9], and not all ints!

Comment: @amit I am not sure if you are a troll or not, you have been provided with all the code, test it for yourself before bashing. Now lets break down your comments, I am genuinely interested in the explanation if any of your remarks are valid. 1. The order of the methods, first I run both methods 1 000 000 to warm up the JIT. Then I got almost identical benchmark time for benchmark 1,3 and 2,4.? 2. Where do my solution create new String objects? Locally in the for loop wouldn't it be true that the gc removes and not require more space but instead less?

Comment: Of course it only works for the range [-9,9] have you read the question? At first I had an implementation for all int but only got it twice as fast as the split, look at my edits and you can see the implementation and benchmark for that. Then I say it was only single digit ints and optimized it further.

Comment: @Farmor: not trolling, pointing things for improvement. Though the example specifies numbers in [-9,9], the question doesn't indicate it. `s.subString()` creates a new `String` object and returns it. I am really interested if trying this approach for all range `int`s will be efficient or not, and I suspect it won't because of the `subString()` usage, but of course I might be wrong. any answer to this last question will make me smile, as I just learned something new.

Comment: I will make a new answer as the code will be to long in a comment. If you look at the s.subString() you will see it's nested inside the for loop and will be garbage collected. For split you will have all string objects in memory, in my solution every single sub string one for each int will be eligible for gc after each int has been processed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to comment discussion.
This answer works for all ints.
It's significantly faster than the split.

```
1295ms my
2193ms split
1155ms my
1889ms split
```

code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class FarmorsOptimized {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "32324 -324 873249 -8544876 -74093 -3243274 4325 643286 92325 -21376218 -213 2132531 2314 1 2";
    int times = 1000000;
    long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getFarmors(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getSplits(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getFarmors(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        getSplits(s);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private static ArrayList getFarmors(String s) {
    ArrayList intArr = new ArrayList();
    int stopvalue = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < stopvalue;) {
        int j = 0;
        while (true) {
            if ((i + j) == stopvalue || s.charAt(i + j) == ' ') {
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        intArr.add(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + j)));
        i += j + 1;
    }
    return intArr;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private static ArrayList getSplits(String s) {
    ArrayList intArr = new ArrayList();
    String[] strArr = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length ; i++){
        intArr.add(Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]));
    }
    return intArr;
}
```

}

Comment: much more intresting result then your previous answer. +1